# Log4j XML configuration debug level issue

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j xml configuration for my project, NOT log4j.properties file. I am trying to display debug messages in eclipse console. But it didn't worked out. Instead, info messages are being displayed.

Below is my log4j xml configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <level value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

In my code I am checking what log level is set this way

```
if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()){
            LOG.debug("debug is enabled");
            LOG.info("Debug enabled but using info to display this message");
            System.out.println("sys out debug is enabled");
}
```

My eclipse console log output is hereunder:

```
12:08:51,191 INFO  [com.abc.servlets.MainServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Debug enabled but using info to display this message
12:08:51,192 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) sys out debug is enabled
```

Additional Information : I am using Jboss App server.

Still working on this, it didn't strike for me where I was wrong.

Comment: Everything looks perfect however I want to suggest some silly idea. Put the root node before the appender and lets give it a try...

Answer (score 2):

Should it be

```
<priority value ="debug" />
```

instead of

```
<level value ="debug" />
```

in

```
 <root> 
    <level value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>
```

Comment: Whenever you downvote, please leave a comment for me to learn for future.